# How to connect to a Rabbit-MQ server over the network?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp

I've got 3 clients on 3 different computers.

Client A is running a RabbitMQ server.

Client B is a producer.

Client C is a consumer.

I've gone through the tutorials on RabbitMQ's site (in Python) and I thought that changing them to work from `localhost` to over the network would just be to just enter the IP in the line:

`connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))`

Their guide even stated

> If we wanted to connect to a broker on a different machine we'd simply specify its name or IP address here.

So what am I doing wrong and how can I get the clients to talk to the server over the network?

Edit: For clarification - I'm running the server using the `rabbitmq-server` command. 
The clients are connected to the broker using the line stated above.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError: Connection to <ip>:<port> failed: [Errno 61] Connection refused`.

Answer (score 0):

By default it will try and connect using guest as the user id and password, and also by default guest will not work from a remote machine, you need to either create a new user and use those credentials in your connection 
e.g.

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('serverip', credentials=credentials)
```

or modify the guest user to allow it to connect from remote machines. The former is probably the better option, directions for the latter option can be found here.

http://blog.shippable.com/rabbitmq-on-docker-fix

Comment: Regarding what you said, the credentials are set up using the `rabbitmqctl`. Am I correct?

Also, rom rabbitmq's site and the example config file I understand that I need to change the host address as it is set by default to: `{tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672},...}`. Is this correct?

Comment: maybe you can do it with rabbitmqctl, I use the management plugin https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: In terms of enabling guest, it's not an issue of changing the host address, it is a matter of removing guest from a group called loopback_users, members of this group can only connect from localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username','password')
parameters = pika.URLParameters('amqp://username:password@localhost:5672/%2F')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
```

If you want to connect to broker on different machine , change the "localhost" above to  name or IP address of that machine :
For example on client B :

```
parameters = pika.URLParameters('amqp://username:password@(ip of client A):5672/%2F')
```